# exchange data within objects (widgets) in python (using pyqt)

Tags: python, oop, pyqt, pyqt4

I am having difficulties with finding the solution to the following problem. Here is the main file:

**main_window.py**

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        #    MBD system
        self.MBDsystem = MBDsystem(folder_name = "dynamic_system_1")

        #    sets opengl widget in central widget position
        self.OpenGLWidget = OpenGLWidget(folder_name = MBS_folder_name, MBD_system = self.MBDsystem)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.OpenGLWidget)
```

I create an object `self.MBDsystem` that contains several list of objects, ie.: list of bodies (with its properties), list of forces...

The plan is to take the created object (and its data) to perform computation and to display every, lets say, 10th step in `self.OpenGLWidget`.

**opengl_widget.py**

```
class OpenGLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, folder_name = None, MBD_system = None):

    QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    #    init GL
    def initializeGL(self):
        #    background color - default color
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1)
        ....

    #   display geometry
    def paintGL(self):
        #   drawing is done here
        ....
```

I would like to know how can this be solved as the **main_window.py** is the GUI and it runs continuously and also the `OpenGLWidget`. 
I would like that computation is done in different method (and file, ie. `solve()` in **solver.py**) for clarity and when the computation solves every 10th step the `OpenGLWidget` displays the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `solve()` is in a different file, import that module, initialize as appropriate, then 
make the `solve()` and the `paingGL()` called via timers. See the [QTimer docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) for several ways to do this, but probably the easiest is to use `QObject::startTimer()` to run `OpenGLWidget::timerEVent()` in which you call both `solve()` and `paingGL()`, but at different intervals. For instance you might call `solve()` at every call of `timerEvent()`, but `paintGL()` only every 10th call:

```
    import solver

    class OpenGLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None, folder_name = None, MBD_system = None):
            QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)
            self.solveCount = 0
            solver.init()
            interval = 10 # milliseconds
            self.startTimer(10)

        def timerEvent(self, event):
            solver.solve()
            self.solveCount += 1
            if self.solveCount > 10:
                 self.paintGL()
                 self.solveCount = 0
```

If the interval is 0 the `timerEvent()` will be called only when GUI is not busy (it is the equivalent of idle callback in wxPython and other GUI APIs).

As explained on that doc page, you could also run `solve()` in a `QThread`. You would have to synchronize the call to `paintGL()` so that `solve()` isn't writing to data at the same time as `paintGL` is reading it. This complexity is only useful if `solve()` is really sensitive to time step, and even then, there are other ways of doing this. For instance while the user is resizing a window, the GUI is busy non-stop: if the user holds on to the window border for 5 seconds while resizing, it is likely that `timerEvent()` will not be called for 5 seconds. Your solve would then have to subdivide the time step since last call (5 sec) into N smaller steps (500 steps of 10 ms each).

Comment: Thanks for the nice help @Schollii. I had to change the line:
`self.startTimer(10)` to:

`#    timer settings
     timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
     timer.setInterval(10)  # msec
     QtCore.QObject.connect(timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'), self.timerEvent)
     timer.start()`

And it works. I would like that `timerEvent(self, event)` would start after a user would trigger when **start** button is pressed. Any suggestions?

Comment: You would move the `self.startTimer(10)` to a function that constructor connects to your button.